# How to fill the table with JsonDataSource in Jaspersoft studio?

Tags: json, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have json file:

```
{
  "apples": [
    {"yellow":2},
    {"red":5},
    {"green":10}
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to create a table in "Jaspersoft studio", however I'm facing a problem with dataset for table when creating it. It only allows to choose one object from array, not the whole array. What am I doing wrong?
Here are screenshots: 
[image: Datasource]
[image: Fields]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your json datasource is incorrect, it does not have a correct structure that can be easily used by any system trying to parse it, since the properties are not know but instead dynamic.

It should have been something like this:

```
[
 {"color": "yellow","number": 2},
 {"color": "red","number": 5},
 {"color": "green","number": 10}
]
```

What you should do now is to teach the providers of this datasource to create a correct and usable json, if this is impossibile and you are stuck with this random text, I would probably use java to restructure it. Use a json parser and as you encounter tokens add the data in a structured way to a list of objects, then pass this list of objects to jasper report.